# running jps command not showing NameNode or Tasktracker ID, though it statrs up when i use start.sh command

Tags: hadoop

the jps command should show the ID against

```
JPS
NameNode
TaskTracker
JobTracker
```

But I am getting only the JPS along with its ID. The rest of it is working fine.

```
4801 Jps
```

I tried posting the screen shot for convenience but was not allowed as I don't have 10 points or something like that.

If there is some other way of doing it, if u need to view the screen shot to help me solve my issue, please tell me.
With Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you have started hadoop services with sudo then you need to run JPS with sudo privilege.

```
$ sudo jps
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect NameNode *isn't* running. Have you tried

```
ps -fe | grep -i namenode
```

or similar ?

Comment: This is the output when i run the above-mentioned command........ hduser    5178  4049  0 15:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i namenode

Comment: hduser    5178  4049  0 15:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i namenode

Comment: Are you executing `jps` with user `hduser`? If you are, then namenode is not running. If you are not, run `jps` as root (or sudo).

Comment: yes. I have created a dedicated user hduser to run hadoop. And previously NameNode used to run even in this mode, then why not now?  Running jps as root gives me an error message telling me jps command not found

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, none of the hadoop daemons are running. How you are starting the cluster?

Comment: i CD to hadoop's home directory. then i CD to /bin. then i type "start-all.sh"..... It shows me messages like "starting namenode, starting tasktracker" and all... But on doing jps, i am returned only the jps with the ID but not the namenode, datanode and the tasktracker. But previously, just few days back only, I used to get all the IDs of tasktracker, jobtracker and namenode when i executed in the same way

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and this got me done.
Try editing your **~/.bashrc** properly.
I did skip the **~/.bashrc** accidentally in my installation process earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You are only shown ID because you haven't started hadoop first.Before running jps you have to start hadoop by using start-all.sh now you can run jps.Then you will be getting the required output