# jps command list only jps but still HDFS services are available

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am currently using a 5 node cluster for Hadoop. If I execute the jps command on Namenode, i can only see Jps process running.

```
[user1@p03517 ~]$ /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/jps
16641 Jps
```

Hive uses HDFS for storage. So,in this case, my select queries should fail with a connection error. But, I can fetch data using the query.

```
[user1@p03517 ~]$ hive
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.4.0.0-169/0/hive-log4j.properties
hive> select * from test_hive;
OK
1       2       95
2       2       90
Time taken: 6.52 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> exit;
```

I am unable to explain this HDFS behavior. I tried to see the report. But, only superuser can see the report.

```
[user1@p03517 ~]$ hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

EDIT 1:
Since I am not the superuser, so `sudo jps` did not work.
I am using the below command instead as a workaround:

```
ps -ef | grep -i namenode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the information you have provided.

As you have mentioned , you are not the `super user`.

- To check all running nodes on the host via `jps`, you need to run the
  command as root.
- Otherwise, `jps` will only show nodes which you
  have currently logged-in user as.

This link also throws more light on a similar issue :

[running jps command not showing NameNode or Tasktracker ID, though it statrs up when i use start.sh command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270571/running-jps-command-not-showing-namenode-or-tasktracker-id-though-it-statrs-up)

Hope it answers your query!!

Comment: Thanks Keshav. Is there way to check which services are running using Java ? I actually want to verify that services are running before firing Hive queries.